how to generate hours like calendar()?
I want to generate a model every two hours and make calculations on each row, just like the calendar().
I have already had calendar() in my model to generate some days. How can I join the days with a set of hours in DAX?
so like:
4/27/2024 0:00
4/27/2024 2:00
4/27/2024 4:00
......

4/28/2024 0:00
4/28/2024 2:00
4/28/2024 4:00
...

4/29/2024 0:00
...
.......


I realised I can do this in M. All problems sorted
let
    Source = List.Dates(#date(1901, 1, 1), 54405, #duration(1,0,0,0)),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
in
    #"Converted to Table"

